# Julia , Pyplot without conda

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia

How can I set up my Julia installation to use PyPlot by calling my native Python and not install the huge and mostly useless conda? If I could use a Python virtual environment (set up with venv) that would be even better.

OS = Fedora 32, Julia = 1.4.2

Answer (score 1):

You can try to tell `PyCall` to use your local Python installation rather than Julia in-built.

```
ENV["PYTHON"]="/path_to/bin/python"
using Pkg
pkg"build PyCall"
```

Now whatever you have in Python should be available.

For more details also see: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#specifying-the-python-version

Comment: Thanks that worked. I used  ENV["PYTHON"]="/usr/bin/python"  then Pkg.add("PyCall")